# Google Info Window: clicking on a link causes page to reload

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm doing some tests for a web page I have to design; thus, I wrote some code to add markers on a map and add an Info Window for each of them containing some info:

```
function placeAttractionMarker(lat, lon, icon_path, name, url)
{
    //generate marker's info
    var contentString = '<div id="content"><div id="siteNotice">' +
    '</div><div id="bodyContent"><h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' +  name + '</h4>' +
        '<a href=""' + url + ' style="text-decoration:none"><b>Sito web</b></a></div></div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    (
        {
            position: markerPos,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: icon_path,
            title: name
        }
    );

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}
```

This function is invoked for each marker to be added to map:

```
 for(var j = 0; j<interest_points.length; j++)
    {
        placeAttractionMarker(
            interest_points[j].Lat,
            interest_points[j].Lon,
            "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/orange/blank.png",
            interest_points[j].Name,
            interest_points[j].Wikipedia
        );
    }
```

The resulting info page correctly contains all the info, URL comprised. Anyway, when I click on URL, my page containing map is simply reloaded.
On website where I found sample code ([Google Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)), on clicking a page is loaded and substituted to map. This is a behaviour I don't like, considering that loaded page can't be scrolled and only a part is visible (according to size of original map).
I would like user to click on link inside Info Window and a new tab to open, to show loaded page.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I think `'<a href=""' + url + '` should be `'<a href="' + url + '"'` so that your url is actually inside the href attribute.

Comment: yes, thanks, that was the problem. now everything seems correct. Anyway, when I click on it, no page is loaded because I'm using XAMPP for local tests on localhost.
Is there a way to solve this problem? Should I write a new specific question for this?

Comment: No idea tbh. You could try updating this question, but more people will see a new question with a title relevant to the xampp localhost problem.

Comment: luckly I solved myself. now I just need to force page loading in a new tab... :(

Comment: thank you man. you saved me half a hour of web searching :)
it perfectly worked.